# How can I plot categorical pattern in R?

Tags: r

```
Year        Dist        Ratio
<int>       <chr>       <dbl>
2018        A       1.576287
2018        B       3.487632
2018        C       2.827363
2019        A       2.176387
2019        B       1.326874
2019        C       1.728745

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = Ratio))
```

but it shown

[image]

[How can I plot similar pattern to the picture?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0K5m.png)

Answer (score 2):

Are you after this?

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = Ratio, color = Dist))
```

[image]

---

Or following @Konrad Rudolph' comment, we can convert `Year` into `date` type, e.g.,

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = as.Date(paste0(Year,"-01-01")), y = Ratio, group = Dist))
```

Comment: I think that’s what OP is after, though that x-axis is suspect. ;-) I guess the easiest way would be to convert the `Year` variable into dates, to make ‘ggplot2’ choose a more appropriate scale.

Comment: @Konrad. The OP commented : "If then i wish to input dist (categorical variable) as my x-axis, how can i do in my coding part?" Therefore I think he wants to plot ratio at each `Dist` by `Year`. But it is only a guess.

Comment: @TarJae In that case, yours is the answer to OP. Upvoted yours!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
df <- tribble(
~Year,        ~Dist,        ~Ratio,
2018, "A", 1.576287, 
2018, "B", 3.487632, 
2018, "C", 2.827363, 
2019, "A", 2.176387, 
2019, "B", 1.326874, 
2019, "C", 1.728745)

df$Year <- as.factor(df$Year)
df$Dist <- as.factor(df$Dist)
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Dist, y = Ratio, colour = Year, group = Year)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the linked image, the x-axis is *categorical*, and is so because the variable passed in `aes(x = ...)` is a character vector or factor vector.

In your case, `Year` is numerical, hence the x-axis is interpreted as a *nominal* scale, as you can have 2018, 2018.9, 2018.999, 2019.0, 2020 (never mind that it doesn't necessarily makes sense in your case).

To force the x-axis, convert the `Year`-variable into a factor, as such:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = as.factor(Year), y = Ratio)) +
  labs(x="Year")
```

Comment: If then i wish to input dist (categorical variable) as my x-axis, how can i do in my coding part?

Comment: `dist` is already a categorical variable. Simply specify `aes(x = dist, y = Ratio)`.